# Rails csv import encoding trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, encoding

I have such code for importing to db:

```
require 'csv'
    CSV.foreach("/#{Rails.public_path}/uploads_prices/acc.csv", {:encoding => "ISO-8859-15:UTF-8", :col_sep => ";", :row_sep => :auto, :headers => :none}) do | row |
      @accum = Accumulator.new
      @accum.model = row[2]
      @accum.description = row[2]
      #@cross = OtherProductsCrossList.new
      logger.warn(row[1])
      logger.warn(row[2])


        if @accum.save
          if @accum.persisted?
            @accum.other_products_cross_lists.create(:cross_value => row[1], :distributor_id => 1, :product_type_id => 2)
          end
        end
    end
```

My file looks like this:

```
Код № по каталогу  (артикул)    Наименование  товара    Ед. изм.    Цена опт.   Доп.    Остатки | Минск Класс   Группа  Бренд
96528   AH-36АЕТ    ASIAN HORSE 36з евр (тонк.кл.) 280A (187x127x227)                                                       шт      38,58           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
96529   AH-36АRТ    ASIAN HORSE 36з рус (тонк.кл.) 280A (187x127x227)                                                       шт      38,58           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
88634   AH-45АЕТ    ASIAN HORSE 45з евр 300A (238x129x227) (545158033)                                                      шт      46,14           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
82978   AH-45АЕ ASIAN HORSE 45з евр 300A тонк.клемы  (238x129x227) (545157033)                                          шт      36,57       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
96531   AH-60АЕ ASIAN HORSE 60з евр 510A (232x173x225)                                                                  шт      48,76           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
82979   AH-70АЕ ASIAN HORSE 70з евр 600A (261x175x220)                                                                  шт      56,92       3   Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
96530   AH-70АR ASIAN HORSE 70з рус 600A (261x175x220)                                                                  шт      56,92       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
82980   AH-95АЕ ASIAN HORSE 95з евр 760A (306x173x225)                                                                  шт      77,21       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
96532   AH-95АR ASIAN HORSE 95з рус 760A (306x173x225)                                                                  шт      77,21       >8  Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      ASIAN HORSE до 100А                                                                                     АКБ ASIAN HORSE
25335   600 103 085 Бэрен polar 100з (600103) 850A (353x175x190)                                                            шт      107,42          Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
102137  600 150 087 / L5 100    Бэрен polar 100з (600150) 870A (353x175x190)                                                            шт      94,7            Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
25332   544 111 042 / L1B 44    Бэрен polar 44з (544111) 420A (207x175x175)                                                             шт      47,83       4   Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
70160   544 150 039 Бэрен polar 44з (544150) 390A (175x175x190)                                                             шт      56,94           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
70165   550 122 054 Бэрен polar 50з (550122) 540A (242x175x175)                                                             шт      63,21           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
102134  554 150 052 / L1 54+    Бэрен polar 54з (554150) 520A (207x175x190)                                                             шт      55,92           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
107894  554 150 054 / L2B 54    Бэрен polar 54з (554150) 520A (242x175x175)                                                             шт      60,93           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
27574       Бэрен polar 55/59з (555112) 480A (242x175x190)                                                          шт      51,72           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
70161   555 114 051 Бэрен polar 55з (555114) 510A (207x175x190)                                                             шт      58,56           Аккумуляторы и электрооборудование                                                                      BAREN до 100 A                                                                                          АКБ BAREN
```

but for Asian horse i see in db Asian horse, but for Бэрен polar  i see Áýðåí polar. How can i told rails that it must correctly import russian symbols?

Also file is here:
[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59666091/acc.csv)

Comment: @brabester1992 Hope this help `http://pastie.org/5115113`

Comment: using this for encoding r:ISO-8859-15:UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing helps... But i tried with many encoding in phpmyadmin, and set that is good for my question (cp1251bin)... don't know my before it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Add a `# encoding: UTF-8` line at the beginning of your ruby code file. And this in-depth explanation on Ruby encodings by [JEG](https://twitter.com/JEG2) helps a lot: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings